# PHP Regex and DocComment Value Parsing

Tags: php

I am trying to parse the value a doc block comment

```
$str = "/**
 * @title View/List Permissions
 * @description Allow user to view list of permissions
 */";
```

The code that I am using is shown below:

```
$re = "/^.*@title\s+(\S*).*@description\s+(\S*).*$/s"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

The current result is as follows:

```
[0] View/List
[1] Allow
```

https://regex101.com/r/dA7jW2/2

What can I do to get the the fill "View/List Permissions" and "Allow user to view list of permissions"?

I have tried to modify the regex by replacing the \s+(\S*).* with \s+(\S.*) and while it works to some extent, it is adding the * from the next line

https://regex101.com/r/dA7jW2/3

Any ideas will  help..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `\S` to `[^\n]` and matched the rest of the string to the end of the line.

```
^.*@title\s+([^\n]*).*@description\s+([^\n]*).*$
```

Outputs:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [14-35] `View/List Permissions`
2.  [52-90] `Allow user to view list of permissions`
```

https://regex101.com/r/dA7jW2/4

That `[^]` is a negative character class, so you can list all the characters you don't want to match. `[^\n]` says match character that's not a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/^.*@title\s+(.*)\s*\*\s*@description\s+(.*).*$/s
```

The problems you are having are:

1) When you do `(\S*)` it stops after the first whitespace character you get to (in this case, a space), so you need to do `(.*)`

2) You need to handle any number of spacing after "Permissions" (spaces or return characters), followed by a `*`, followed by any additional whitespace before "@description"

Hope that helps